# What are community answers and why / when to use them?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

I have seen some community wiki answers laying around the site, I am wondering when should one use it and the main reason for them to exist.

Can moderators convert a user answer to community wiki?

ie: a user makes a great answer with a lot of votes up, but the answer is outdated and the user in no where to be seen. I know you can downvote and create a new answer but maybe it can be converted to community wiki and edited to best fit the current situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit answers even if they're not community wiki. It just reduces the reputation requirements to be able to edit without approval if a post is CW. The main use of CW is to directly invite others to edit the post.

And yes, moderators can convert to community wiki, but I don't think that it necessary just because an answer is outdated.

[From a more general question on Meta.SO I answered a while ago:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108137/151385)

> From the [blog post on Community Wiki from Grace Note](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/):
>
> > The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of
> >     solving a question. An incomplete “seed” answer is a stepping stone to
> >     a complete solution with help from others; an incomplete question is a
> >     hindrance and an obstacle to getting a solution as no one understands
> >     the inquiry. It is in answers that the goal of community wiki, for the
> >     community, by the community, shows its truest colors.
>
> If you know that your answer is incomplete and you want to encourage
>   other users to add information to it, you can make it CW to invite
>   others to edit the answer. Since everyone can propose edits, community
>   wiki is not necessary anymore for collaborative answers, so it has
>   lost a lot of its usefulness. It is now more of an invitation for
>   other users to edit, but it is not really a technical necessity
>   anymore.
>
> It is rather used as a sign for others that you don't mind, and even
>   encourage other users to edit the post. Many users hesitate to make
>   big changes to posts belonging to other users, CW means you relinquish
>   the sole ownership of the answer and encourage other users to add to
>   the answer.

Comment: Great, thx that was information enough.